# How to change checked checkbox (select all) after i uncheck one of the following checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

i just created check all script in JS, but dont have any idea how to implement checking if all my checkboxes are still checked, and if not - unchecking my "select all" checkbox. Any ideas on how to?

here is my code to have a look at, pure JS

```
function toggle() {
    let selector = document.querySelector('.chbx_selector');
    let selection = document.querySelectorAll('.chbx_selection');

    selector.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (selector.checked === true) {
            selectAll(selection)
        }
        else {
            deselectAll(selection)
        }

    });
}

function selectAll (selection) {
    selection.forEach(chbx => {
        chbx.checked = true;
    });
}

function deselectAll (selection) {
    selection.forEach(chbx => {
        chbx.checked = false;
    });
}

toggle()
```

I seem to have run out of mental ability to solve the problem, although im still trying some things with eventListener click type in hopes ill reach the expected result. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please add any relevant JavaScript code/HTML markup/CSS to your question as a [mcve], (you can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you.), and then describe in a little more detail what the problem that you're facing is.

Comment: Add a click listener to all the checkboxes (except the checkall checkbox). In the event, check if the checkbox was set to checked or not, and if not uncheck your checkAll checkbox.

Comment: `document.querySelector('.chbx_selector').checked = [...document.querySelectorAll(".chbx_selection")].every(cb => cb.checked);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanielBlack, your answer helped me resolve the problem and it works perfectly now! I was pouching around this for a while but couldnt get to the correct answer. I guess writing code while exhausted isnt as easy as i thought

Comment: @DanielBlack if you could i'd love if u posted your comment as answer so i can mark question as resolved. Thanks once again!

Comment: @MaxSien I've added my comment as an answer now. Glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up an event listener on the non checkall checkboxes. Within this event you can check the checked status of the checkbox, and if unchecked, update the checkall checkbox to uncheck it.

This way whenever any of the other checkboxes are unchecked your checkall checkbox will stay in sync.